# Filling cells in Excel with values from Access using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I want to create macro that can give barcode number from Access db where it's "*" in the cell. With my code i always get the error 13:Type mismatch. The macro should search every cell as long as there is a value in cells(row,1) and also table header....

With this code the barcode is not even given and i think vba has a hard time with the loop and i just can't figure out

this is my code:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, sql As String
    Dim row As Long
    Dim column As Long
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = Sheets("Test")
    
    On Error GoTo ErrHndler
    
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    
    
    With cn
        .ConnectionString = con1
        .Open
    End With
    
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "Barcode", cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    
    row = 4
    column = 1
    
    While (Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(row, 1))) And Not rs.EOF
        While (Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(3, column))) And Not rs.EOF
            If ws.Cells(row, column).Value = "*" Then
            ws.Cells(row, column) = rs!BN
            rs!Stand = "used"
            rs.MoveNext
            End If
            column = column + 1
            Wend
        column = 1
        row = row + 1
        
    Wend
    
    sql = "DELETE * FROM Barcode WHERE ((Barcode.Stand)='used');"
    
    cn.Execute (sql)
    
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing
    
Exit Sub
```

Could someone mabe give me a tip! i would realld appreciate it!

Comment: Try `sql = "DELETE FROM Barcode WHERE Stand='used'"`

Comment: Try to debug your code first, see if the database connection is established (opened) and whether looping gets you any data. Maybe your query is not satisficed, etc.

Comment: Hello @NoChance i did debug it and it says the missmatch is on this line: If ws.Cells(row, column).Value = "*" .... the db connection is fine

Comment: @CDP1802 is it because some of the cells are string and some are numbers?

Comment: Add `Debug.Print row, column, ws.Cells(row, column).Value` before `If ws.Cells(row, column).Value = "*" Then` and check last line in immediate window.

Comment: Looping code works for me - matches asterisk character in cell. What is value in cell when error triggers? Why do you show `Exit Sub` instead of `End Sub`?

Comment: There is Error values in the cells :) so its when it comes to error

Comment: You're updating your recordset fields but you don't call (eg) `rs.Update` to update your source table...

Comment: Add a `If Not IsError(...) Then` conditional before checking for asterisk.

Comment: @TimWilliams, that is not necessary with ADO recordset. Moving to next record in recordset or to EOF will force update of source table. Note there is not a command to put recordset into edit mode - arguments of Open method determine editability.

Comment: @June7 - my bad - been a long time since did that...   Needs client-side cursor though?

Comment: @TimWilliams, I actually don't know what that means. Connection code posted works. Of course, I had to supply connection string for the con1 variable. Recordset is looped and fields edit, passing into table. I do find it odd that recordset and sheet row orders coincide.